# What is the right way to overload the assignment operator for a derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, operator-overloading, c++17

Let's say I have a `Base` class:

```
class Base
{   
    public:
        Base(float x, float y, float z, float w): 
                    x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w) {}
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        float w;
};
bool operator==(const Base &a, const Base &b);
```

Now, I have a `Derived` class from `Base`:

```
class Derived: public Base {
    public:
        Derived(float x, float y, float z)
            : Base(x, y, z, 0)
            , r(x), g(y), b(z)
            {};
        float r;
        float g;
        float b;
};
```

Now, suppose I want to write an overloaded assignment operator for my `Derived` class. Currently, this is what my code looks like:

```
Derived& Derived::operator=(const Derived &a){
    x = a.r;
    y = a.g;
    z = a.b;
    
    r = a.r;
    g = a.g;
    b = a.b;

    return *this;
}
```

I need to assign the `x`, `y` and `z` members of the `Base` class as above, because the `==` operator for my `Derived` class is the overloaded `==` operator of the `Base` class, which uses those members. Consider this snippet, for instance (assuming `x`, `y` and `z` weren't assigned in the overloaded assignment operator):

```
Derived a = Derived(1,2,3);
Derived b = Derived(1,2,3);

bool val = (a == b); // true!

b = Derived(4,5,6);

bool val = (a == b); // still true because b.x, b.y and b.z haven't changed!
```

I feel like I'm doing this the wrong way; shouldn't assignment of a derived class be concerned with only the derived class members? But how do I make it compatible with the overloaded operators of the base class? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: It smells like your hierarchy violates [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  But I'm assuming that it's just a contrived example in support of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an `operator=` in the `Base` class, you could write:

```
Derived& Derived::operator=(const Derived &a){
    
    Base::operator=(static_cast<Base const&>(a));    

    r = a.r;
    g = a.g;
    b = a.b;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: While I like the direction of this answer, I think it's wrong.  The call to the `base::operator=` needs to pass `a`